# How do I copy products from one Opportunity to another in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

So I have a trigger on Order in a certain condition I need to create another opportunity based on the Order's current opportunity. It was pretty straight forward except for getting the products to copy over.

I know this is a high level description, but can anyone help with how I should go about doing this?

*removed code because it had unrelated issues. Will add back when resolved.

Comment: All you should need to do is make copies of the OpportunityLineItems, similar to how you've copied your Opportunity. What part specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: I don't have a opp id yet to associate copied products to the opp since it hasn't been inserted yet. I'm thinking of keeping two lists. One the opp list I'm inserting and one that is a list of product lists. Then after insert of opps, I can loop through and add opp ids to the products. It just feels like there should be an easier way.

Comment: That's exactly how you'll have to do it. Insert the Opportunity and then insert the OpportunityLineItems once you have the Id, there isn't another way in Apex.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an outline solution that should meet your requirements and be bulkified:

1. Get the Ids of the Opportunity records that meet your criteria from your quotes and store them in a `Set<Id>`
2. Query for those Opportunities with the fields you want to clone and store them in a `List<Opportunity>`
3. Loop through this list and add clones of your Opportunities to a `Map<Id, Opportunity>` which maps the original Opportunity Id to the newly cloned Opportunity
4. `insert` your cloned Opportunity records (you can simple call insert on your Map `values()`)
5. Query for all OpportunityLineItem records with `OpportunityId` equal to the `keySet()` of your map and store them in a `List<OpportunityLineItem>`
6. Loop through these and put them in a `Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>` which maps the `OpportunityId` to it's OpportunityLineItem records
7. Loop through your `Map<Id, Opportunity>` from step 3, use the key of your map (the original Opportunity Id) to get the OpportunityLineItem records from your `Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>` in step 6, clone the records, update the Id from the value of your map (the Opportunity record your inserted earlier, which will now have an Id) in your `Map<Id, Opportunity>` and then add them to a `List<OpportunityLineItem>`
8. Finally, `insert` your list of OpportunityLineItem

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your "certain condition" refers to a trigger running After Update on Order.

If that is the case, you should have no problem to query for the Opp's OppLineItems, create a new set based on the properties of this old set (all the variables you want to keep, except the ones that are system created like ID and such) and link them properly.

But you already seem to know that, what is specifically your problem at "getting the products to copy over?"
Do you have any sample code or anything that we could look at to help you?

As a wild guess, keep in mind that if you query an object you have to specify every field you want to fetch of it, for example, if you query an Account with the SOQL "[Select Name from Account Where SOMETHING]", and you create a new Account with the info you just fetched, you won't have anything else but the Name of it.

Hope any of this helped you and not complicated things more for you!
Cheers!